# Getting different results with the sort command

Tags: linux, sorting, uniq

Trying to sort a file with multiples occurring lines and return a text that only occurs once.

I am trying the over the wire game to increase my Linux proficient, but I run into a question...

In level 8 -> 9 the password for the next level is stored in the file `data.txt` and is the only line of text that occurs only once. I researched and came to the following answer:

```
 $ sort -cu data.txt
```

It printed a single output:

> sort: data.txt:2: disorder: desthMrvBwFuSWkom7FP8ASJayNlfoRd

I expected sorting the file and returning a unique line, but I was not sure if it was the right one. So I did some more research, now using stackoverflow and others communities and find another solution:

```
$ sort data.txt| uniq -u
```

It printed a different output:

```
1 EN632PlfYiZbn3PhVK3XOGSlNInNE00t
```

I don't understand why the first command is not returning the right password, and returning a line that is repeated.

Answer (score 1):

The `-c` option doesn't sort, it checks if the file is already sorted